# How to get maximum size of MySQL row?

Tags: mysql

I tried creating a table, and got the "Row size too large" error. No problem, I just changed some of the large VARCHAR fields to TEXT, and it worked. But now I have no idea how close I am to the row size limit. How do I determine the maximum row size for a table?

MySQL version: 5.5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the **storage engine** you use and the **row format** chosen for that table, and also your **indexes**. It's hard to calculate because the database is able to constantly change its structure.

But the VARCHAR, TEXT and BLOB are a variable-length data types, it has a length property, but the value can be empty; calculation may be not exact. Have a look at `Avg_row_length` field in `information_schema.tables`.

EDIT: Have a look at: [Data Type Storage Requirements](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/storage-requirements.html).

Comment: I was hoping for something a little more polished, but the scripts in the link you posted are close enough to what I want. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There's some rough guidelines in the [MySQL documentation on row-size limits](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/column-count-limit.html) that might help.

Remember that *bytes* and *characters* are not equivalent. A `VARCHAR(255)` in a UTF-8 type table will count as more than one byte per character. By default three bytes are reserved.